# Adding VC2010 compiler to VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have installed VS2012 express.It uses VC11 compiler.I need to add also VC10 compiler to be able working with some older libs.I have installed Windows 7.1 SDK which comes with VC10 compiler.Now I can select VC10 from PlatformToolset.But when compiling I am getting this error:

**Warning   1   warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets    297 5    (Visual Studio 2010)**

Now , I am sure the problem is that I installed the VS not on C but on E.Though Windows SDK I have installed on E too.Somehow I see the config is looking for the "WindowsSDKDir " on C.Where can I change it ?

Comment: I don't because those libs have no sources :) Otherwise wouldn't  bother ;)

Comment: why are you sure the problem is the install path? Also where do you see the config is looking at C? (the c:\... in the error message you show has nothing to do with it, that is just the place where the error is raised.) Anyway afaik `WindowsSDKDir` is just an environment variable. What's the value on your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , finally I fixed it by removing Windows SDK and installing Visual Studio Express 2010.Now VS2012 compiles VC10 fine.